# Live-Kernal Debugging with WinDbg

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg, dump

I am using Microsoft WinDbg on the host machine to perform kernal debugging on the target machine. My aim to is continuously create a dump file on the host computer until my target computer crashes.

Is there a way to do this?

I am able to create a kernal dump file on the host computer with .dump, but only after i stop debugging the target.

Comment: The target and host is connected over a COM port. (Null-modem cable)

Answer (score 0):

run the .dump in a loop maybe (what is your target for dump creation
assuming you are dumping x gb of target when would you stop
if the target never crashed before your host runs out of space maybe ?

running the comment in loop is limited by the counter you use

here i create 5 dumps one after another

```
0:001> .for(r $t0 = 0; @$t0 < 5 ; r $t0 = @$t0+1 ) {.dump /u d:\foo.dmp }
Creating d:\foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-07-973_0fb4.dmp - mini user dump
Dump successfully written
Creating d:\foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-003_0fb4.dmp - mini user dump
Dump successfully written
Creating d:\foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-039_0fb4.dmp - mini user dump
Dump successfully written
Creating d:\foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-076_0fb4.dmp - mini user dump
Dump successfully written
Creating d:\foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-109_0fb4.dmp - mini user dump
Dump successfully written
```

result

```
D:\>dir /b foo*
foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-07-973_0fb4.dmp
foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-003_0fb4.dmp
foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-039_0fb4.dmp
foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-076_0fb4.dmp
foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-109_0fb4.dmp

D:\>fc /b foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-07-973_0fb4.dmp foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-003_0fb4.dmp | head -4
Comparing files foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-07-973_0fb4.dmp and FOO_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-003_0FB4.DMP
00000014: 13 14
0000011C: 03 02
00000A04: C4 5C

D:\>fc /b foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-07-973_0fb4.dmp foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-039_0fb4.dmp | head -4
Comparing files foo_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-07-973_0fb4.dmp and FOO_0788_2018-10-30_00-23-08-039_0FB4.DMP
00000014: 13 14
0000011C: 03 02
00000A04: C4 70

D:\>
```

Comment: I wanted to get the dump file just before it freezes (i.e atleast 5mins data before freeze)

Comment: After connecting with WinDbg over COM port do we need to send any command to start debugging or does .dump \f create a dump until the target crashes?

Comment: you have some misconceptions i think what do you mean when by until ? .dump creates one time dump  it doesnt matter if it is running or crashing  it captures the state of the target at a give point of time   it doesnt wait or doesnt take a trigger you ask for a dump and it provides you one which has the state at the time of capture  a dump is a fossilised remains of some long extinct state of target

Comment: @blabb - The latest Windbg supports Time Travel. Any idea if that's a workable route (otherwise, OP should be collecting a WPR trace)

Comment: @Lieven  op says kernel connection ttd is not an option for kernel mode afaik  havent used ttd lately so not aware if ttd was enabled fir kd in recent releases  and wpr needs src and possible recompilation  cant use for existing srcless symbol less issues